# Make the height for ApexCharts donut chart equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm working with the React version of ApexCharts, and have a number of these charts on the page, I am looking to have all of the charts have equal sizing, however, the size of the charts seems to include the size of the legend when it calculates the chart sizing, causing charts with a number of values to render squashed compared to charts with fewer values.

I am trying to get the chart sizing to not account for the legend size when calculating render size and have the legend be rendered below the fixed-size chart and take up whatever size it needs to.

I've tried reading through the documentation and fiddling with the various chart options available but they all seem to apply sizes and percentages based upon the entire chart container including the legend, not just the chart svg element itself.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: After fiddling with this library on a project (look was sexier than ChartJS), I can only say this library sucks big time, stay away from it. CSS control might seem like an appeal, but it turns out it's grueling to achieve the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the legend out of the flow, you can use

```js
legend: {
  floating: true
}
```

and then set the legend's position using offsets.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, made it worse actually.

Answer (score 0):

As you said "the size of the charts seems to include the size of the legend when it calculates the chart sizing" so removing the legend was the optimal solution for me. and to display the legend visually in the same way, I added styles for the blocks in which the diagram itself is located.

```
legend: {floating: true}
```

and add CSS -

```
svg {
    height: 350px;
    width: 550px;
}
foreignObject {
    height: 350px;
    width: 550px;
}
```

this allowed me to get the same dimensions for different data